# Simple Google Scripts Email Application - POST request failing from Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, post

I am trying to create a simple form on my website that will take a user's name, email, and brief message and send it to Google Apps Script which will then email me with their message. I keep getting a status of failed on my google apps script. I've tried using Logger.log() for debugging, however nothing ever appears on the cloud log when I try to inspect. Here is my front end code in my Javascript:

```
        const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyedfmVexnnu9oTATVADIbe5oYQbrDpmNWGLcrtSpKtFBZWA9RgnugohF9mLCHeGJc4/exec"
        const data = {
            name: $emailName.val(),
            email: $emailEmail.val(),
            message: $emailMessage.val()
        }
        // const payload = JSON.stringify(data)
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: "no-cors",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            payload: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
        console.log(options)
        fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("success", response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        
    })


})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

And here is my Google Script:

```
function doPost(e) {

Logger.log(e);

var reply = JSON.parse(e.parameters.email);
var name = JSON.parse(e.parameters.name);
var message = JSON.parse(e.parameters.message);

newMessage = "You have a new email from " + name + ", and you can reply back to them at email " + reply + ". Message below. \n\n\n\n" + message;

object = {
  to: "************",
  replyTo: reply,
  subject: "New Message from " + name,
  body: newMessage
};

  MailApp.sendEmail(object);

return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));


}
```

Any help diagnosing this problem would be really helpful, I've been troubleshooting for hours and haven't come up with a solution. Thank you!

**SOLUTION**

Front End:

```
        const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/******/exec"
        const data = {
            name: $emailName.val(),
            email: $emailEmail.val(),
            message: $emailMessage.val()
          }
          const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          }
          console.log(options)
          fetch(url, options)
          .then((response) => response.text())
          .then((response) => console.log(response))
          .catch((error) => console.log(error))
        
    })
```

GOOGLE SCRIPT:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var {name, email, message} = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var reply = email;
  newMessage = "You have a new email from " + name + ", and you can reply back to them at email " + reply + ". Message below. \n\n\n\n" + message;
  object = {
    to: "*****",
    replyTo: reply,
    subject: "New Message from " + name,
    body: newMessage
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(object);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(object);
}
```

Please please please make sure to refresh your browser when you do this. I was banging my head against a wall for hours and when I refreshed the browser it somehow accepted everything. Thank you to Tanaike!

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize. And, when I tested your script, I thought that I might have sent an email using your value by my mistake. If you got an email, I apologize for it. Please remove it.

Comment: @Alfredo When I go to the Executions tab in Google Script, it just says "Failed" with no further description. Even though I'm logging the event in an attempt to debug, no log exists which is part of my frustration.

Comment: @Tanaike - thank you for your replay and no worries about the email. Unfortunately even with all of the changes I'm still getting the "Failed" error in my execution log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Modification points:

- At your Javascript side,

  - At `fetch`, please set the data to `body` instead of `payload`.
  - There is no property of `contentType`.
  - In this case, `mode: "no-cors"` is not required to be used.
- At your Google Apps Script side,

  - In this case, the value from `body` can be retrieved from `e.postData.contents`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Javascript side:

```
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
const data = {
  name: $emailName.val(),
  email: $emailEmail.val(),
  message: $emailMessage.val()
}
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
}
console.log(options)
fetch(url, options)
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((response) => console.log(response))
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var {name, email, message} = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var reply = email;
  newMessage = "You have a new email from " + name + ", and you can reply back to them at email " + reply + ". Message below. \n\n\n\n" + message;
  object = {
    to: "taylorhughes291@gmail.com",
    replyTo: reply,
    subject: "New Message from " + name,
    body: newMessage
  };
  MailApp.sendEmail(object);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

### Note:

- When you modified the Google Apps Script for Web Apps, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### References:

- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Sample Scripts for Requesting to Web Apps by Various Languages](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/a72aab0242012362c46ec69031c720d5#sample-scripts-for-requesting-to-web-apps-by-various-languages)
- [Request parameters of Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have made the modified changes and redeployed the web app script, making sure that my front-end reflects the URL. However, I am still getting a result of "Failed" in my execution log in Google Script. Google script seems to not log anything so I am unsure why this is happening. Also, every time I remove the mode: "no-cors" from my options variable, my browser console blocks the POST request because of CORS so I have elected to keep it in.

Would you happen to know of any reason why the script would fail to execute? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Please disregard the last message. Your solution worked! I think my problem was that I wasn't allowing enough time for the script to deploy, and I needed to refresh my browser window in order to accept the new URL to access the script. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @taylorhughes291 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.